# Automatically create a table in oracle database if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm working on a AAA (Authentication and etc..) application in java and i want to know is there a way to check by error code or anything that if the table which i want to insert data in it exists.And if its dropped or any kind of problem occurred to it,the program create the table automatically.
P.S: I've checked other related questions and the answers did not fit the check by the java program thing i want.

Comment: sorry for bad Grammar or any possible mistakes.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd want that kind of thing in a banking application. These systems tend to be locked down pretty much (and for a good reason).

Comment: @Moudiz its more a research to know what way is better or what are the ways to do  in first place.and its java side

Comment: Maybe a good compromise is a "schema management system" like Liquibase or Flyway. Safer than just creating tables when they happen to be missing (which in a banking application should really result in shutdown and extensive audit).

Comment: @Thilo its a AAA application and we need it for our logs table. and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way I know, is this:

```
public static boolean tableExists(String tableName, Connection con) {
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet trs = stmt.executeQuery(
             String.format(
                 "SELECT count(*) from (SELECT 1 FROM %s WHERE ROWNUM = 1) T", 
                 tableName
             )
         )
    ) {
        return trs.next();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("SQLException occurs while checking the table " + tableName, e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**NB:** The standard approach is with `connection.getMetaData().getTables(String catalog, String schemaPattern,String tableNamePattern, String types[])` in  other words with database metadata but you will need to specify the schema name and you need additional privileges on database like oracle, with the approach above you don't have to specify the schema name as it will use the default one and you don't need any additional privilege. Even if it can be considered as a controversial approach, believe me it works pretty well, indeed we have hundreds of customers with it in production.

**NB 2:** If you are a little bit curious, We even generalized this approach in order to make it work on the most used databases, only the query changes a little bit as you can see [here](https://github.com/exoplatform/core/blob/develop/exo.core.component.database/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/services/database/utils/JDBCUtils.java#L73-L122).

Answer (score 3):

I would use all_tables (dictionary) for that:

```
--your procedure
--some logic


--check the table in the dictionary
SELECT count(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM all_tables  s
 WHERE s.table_name = p_table_name;


IF v_count = 0 THEN

....

END IF;


--the rest of logic
```